Finishing a TIKZ Gold Plate with a Correspondingly Finished Title
This post is an addendum to Providing an Authentic Finish to a TIKZ Gold Plate.
Consider the code:
\documentclass{article}

% Compiles with XELATEX

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}


\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=1.5em},
        text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2},
        },
      yshift=#1,
      decorate}}



% Overlay Title

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{PureGold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{3.75pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.65cm);
\draw[color=black,fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}


\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\spaceout[1.5pt]\bfseries\color{white}|RECORD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[1.5pt]\bfseries\color{white}|GOLD}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);
\begin{scope}
%\draw[color=BrooklynGold,fill=MidnightBlue] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.43cm);


\foreach \t in {1,...,360}
    \fill[red!65!black, fill opacity={.24*(sin(2*\t))^2}] (0,0)--(\t:2.5) arc (\t:\t+2:2.5) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{30pt}

\mytitle{\scalefont{3.25}{IVAN}}
\end{center}
\end{document}

with the output:

QUESTION: Is it possible, and if so how, may I incorporate the metallic gold with shading effect within the disk into the associated name of "IVAN" below?
I compile with xelatex.
Thank you.

This can be done with fadings. Unfortunately fadings cause errors in XeLaTeX. You could ignore these (generally a bad idea) or compile in LaTeX and save the image, then use \includegraphics in your XeLaTeX document.
First we create a fading called ivan using tikzfadingfrompicture environment. This will create a cutout to fill later with the gold shiny image.
I turned the shiny transparency that was being overlaid on the gold disk into a pic called shine. Then instead of drawing the semitransparent disk on top of the gold disk, I just placed the pic with \path pic{shine};. Then I reused the pic (clipped) on the ivan fading.
By the way, I got rid of your \mytitle macro and just put the text in a node (in black, shifted down) and then put the shiny IVAN on top of it.

\documentclass{article}

% Compiles with XELATEX

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}


\def\theLetterSpace{0.5pt}
\def\theWordSpace{1.5\LocalLetterSpace}
\newlength\LocalLetterSpace
\newcommand\spaceout[2][\theLetterSpace]{%
  \setlength\LocalLetterSpace{#1}\expandafter\spaceouthelpA#2 \relax\relax}
\def\spaceouthelpA#1 #2\relax{%
  \spaceouthelpB#1\relax\relax%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\ \kern\theWordSpace\spaceouthelpA#2\relax\fi
}
\def\spaceouthelpB#1#2\relax{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \kern\LocalLetterSpace\spaceouthelpB#2\relax%
  \fi
}
 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\tikzset{
    mydecor/.style 2 args={decoration={text along path,
        text align={left indent=1.5em},
        text={|\bfseries\tiny|#2}},
        yshift=#1,
        decorate},
    shine/.pic={
        \foreach \t in {1,...,360}
            \fill[red!65!black, fill opacity={.24*(sin(2*\t))^2}]
                (0,0)--(\t:2.5) arc (\t:\t+2:2.5) -- cycle;
    }
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=ivan]
    \node[text=transparent!0, scale=7]{\bfseries IVAN};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.65cm);
\draw[color=black,fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);

\draw[color=PureGold,fill=black] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);

\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\spaceout[1.5pt]\bfseries\color{white}|RECORD}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.25ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\LARGE\scalefont{0.97}\spaceout[1.5pt]\bfseries\color{white}|GOLD}}}] (192.5:3.07cm) arc (192.5:345:3.07cm);

\draw[color=PureGold,fill=black] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\draw[color=PureGold,fill=PureGold] (0,0) circle (2.43cm);

\path pic{shine};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{30pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip(-3,-1)rectangle(3,1);
\node[scale=7]at (0,-3.75pt){\bfseries IVAN};
\fill[path fading=ivan, fit fading=false, PureGold] circle[radius=3cm] pic{shine};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


Many thanks for your answer.
